# Text doesn't align to the top

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

[The text is aligned to the bottom of the iconfont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl4JJ.png)

I don't know why the name text is aligned to the bottom of the icon-font. I want to align the text to the top of the div .profile-info:

html

```
  <div class="profile">
    <i class="profile-pic fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="profile-info">
      <p class="name">John Doe</p>
      <p class="user-type">Admin</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.profile
  display: table
  padding: 15px

  .profile-pic
    display: table-cell
    font-size: 40px
    padding-right: 10px

  .profile-info
    display: table-cell
    .name
      margin-bottom: 0
      position: relative
    .user-type
      color: grey
```

Comment: any examples? jsFiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to vertically align it to the top. Use this

```
.profile-info
    display: table-cell
    vertical-align: top
```